# Функция возвращающая табличное значение в SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql

Приветствую.

Имеется созданная функция возвращающая табличное значение. В ней, допустим, есть переменная `@x` и временная таблица, которая заполняется полями из запроса. Запрос возвращает две колонки значений: `dir` и `amount`. Нужно сделать следующее:

1. Если dir = 1 тогда [[[@x](/users/267/xalex)](/users/267/xalex)](/users/267/xalex) = [[[@x](/users/267/xalex)](/users/267/xalex)](/users/267/xalex) + amount
2. Если dir = 2 тогда @х = @х - amount

Как мне это реализовать в SQL Server? В PHP я бы сделал так:

```
$x = 0; 
while ( $res = mssql_fetch_array(*результат моего запроса*) )
{
    if ($res['dir'] == 1) $x += $res['amount'];
    else $x -= $res['amount'];
}
```

Comment: Медленная работа скрипта может быть связана не с неэффективностью, а, например, с отсутствием правильных индексов на таблице, из которой выбираете данные. Нужно анализировать все в целом, тут я вряд ли смогу помочь, нужно всю картину в целом видеть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select @x = @x + case when dir = 1 then amount
    when dir = 2 then -amount end
    from ...
```

Comment: new_value будет значение dir?

Comment: Я не уверен, что здесь алиас нужен, потому что вы же в переменную кладете новое значение. Попробуйте сделать такой селект на тестовой табличке, посмотрите, что вернет запросом (должен ничего не вернуть), и что будет в итоге в переменной @x

Comment: Да, обманул, не сработает первый вариант. Сейчас в комменте поправил - этот вариант - работающий, проверил.

Comment: Боже...какой изврат =) За ответ спасибо большое.

Попробовал сделать присвоение переменной в запросе, который заполняет временную таблицу и был послан куда подальше SQL Server`ом: "Инструкция INSERT не может содержать инструкцию SELECT, которая присваивает значения переменной." Как раз это мне и нужно было. Получается чтобы произвести расчёты и заполнить временную таблицу нужно 2 раза делать практически одинаковые (в моём случае) запросы?

Comment: Вы общую задачу функции назовите. Что на входе есть, что на выходе должно получиться. Может это один запрос будет.

Comment: Функция вспомогательная, в неё передаётся 2 параметра, которые получаются в другой функцие.

Хотел лишь узнать как создать блоки условий, в которых можно было работать с несколькими переменными. Что-то наподобие select @x = @x + case 
   when dir = 1 then amount AND @newX = @OldX + amount
   when dir = 2 then -amount AND @newX = @OldX - ABS(amount) end FROM ...

На SQL Server`е первый день программирую, поэтому толком нечего не знаю.

В общем нужно производить некоторые вычисления оперируя значениями из таблицы

Comment: Нет, так с несколькми переменными в SQL не работают, работают с каждой по отдельности, но можно в одном запросе:
select @x = @x + case when dir = 1 then amount
    when dir = 2 then -amount end,
       @newX = @OldX + case when dir = 1 then amount
                       when dir = 2 then -ABS(amount) end
    from ...

Comment: Я так уже сделал но как то это громоздко и некрасиво смотрится. Общий смысл моей возни с SQL Server - медленная работа скрипта, который обращается к базе, выберает значения, производит расчёты и выводит результат на экран. А сейчас я занимаюсь переносом кода скрипта в код SQL Server. З.Ы. К сожаленью лимит комментариев исчерпан...

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t1 table (dir int, amount int)
declare @t2 table (dir int, amount int)
declare @x int = 0

insert into @t1 (dir,amount ) 
values (1,1),(2,1),(1,4),(2,3),(1,5),(2,6)

select * from @t1 

insert @t2 (dir,amount ) 
select dir, amount
from @t1

update @t2 
set @x = amount = @x + amount * (case when dir = 1 then 1 else -1 end)

select * from @t2
```